# How to get the variable value in TFS/AzureDevOps from Build to Release Pipeline?

Tags: tfs, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-build-task, azure-pipelines-release-task

I've defined a variable in my TFS/AzureDevops Build definition (say it's `time`)
and assign the value using PowerShell task within my build definition.

Like,

**Type:** Inline Script.

**Inline script:**

```
$date=$(Get-Date -Format g);
Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=time]$date"
```

You can refer to this [similar example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44746719/7073340)

Now I want to get this value in my release definition pipeline. I configured this build definition as continuous deployment to my release definition.

### My Question is

How can I get the value of `time` in my release definition using some other variable? Is this possible?

Comment: What's with the downvotes without comments? He tried all that's reasonable to try!

Comment: If you need to get the build's date, why not retrieve the linked build with the REST API and retrieve the date from that?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The is no official way to pass variables from Build to Release. The only way to accomplish this is to store the values in a file (json, xml, yaml, what have you) and attach that as a Build Artifact. That way you can read the file in the release and set the variable again.

Martin Hinshelwood seems to have gotten frustrated enough by this problem and [turned that functionality into an extension for Azure DevOps Pipelines](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=nkdagility.variablehydration).

> ### Tasks included
>
> - **Variable Save Task** - During your build you can save the variables to a json file stored with your other build assets
> - **Variable Load Task** - During your Release you can load the saved variables and gain access to them.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I'm currently using TFS, this extension currently support with AzureDevOps. Do you have any reference like storing a variable into Json (or) any file and read it through the release pipeline?

Comment: The variable group will be help here ?

Comment: Variable groups will help to share static values across builds and releases.

Comment: Crazy how this is not available out of the box! Thanks Martin!

Answer (score 1):

I found another solution that works even without text files just by using the Azure REST API to get the build parameters.

In my release pipeline I execute this Powershell tasks first to extract any build pipeline parameters:

```
function Get-ObjectMember {
  [CmdletBinding()]
  Param(
      [Parameter(Mandatory=$True, ValueFromPipeline=$True)]
      [PSCustomObject]$obj
  )
  $obj | Get-Member -MemberType NoteProperty | ForEach-Object {
      $key = $_.Name
      [PSCustomObject]@{Key = $key; Value = $obj."$key"}
  }
}

$url = "https://dev.azure.com/$(account)/$(project)/_apis/build/builds/$(Build.BuildId)?api-version=6.0"
$build = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url -Headers @{
    Authorization = "Bearer $env:SYSTEM_ACCESSTOKEN"
}
$params = $build.templateParameters
if ($params) {
  $params | Get-ObjectMember | foreach {
    Write-Host $_.Key : $_.Value
    echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=$($_.Key);]$($_.Value)"
  }
}
```

My build pipeline contained the parameter: `RELEASE_VERSION` and after I executed the above code, I can use `$(RELEASE_VERSION)` in my other release tasks.

Answer (score 0):

What about using a variable within a variable group?

I managed to set the value of a variable in a variable group to a variable coming from a build pipeline, and then to read that variable in a release pipeline.

For that, it is necessary:

- To have previously created the variable group, and the variable (its name identified by `$(variableName)`. Let's assume its value would be stored in `$(variableValue)`).
- To find the variable group ID (stored in `$(variableGroupId)`), which can be done by navigating on Azure DevOps to that variable group. The group ID will then be in the URL.
- A Personal Access Token (PAT) with Read & Write access to group variables (called `$(personalAccessToken)` )

**CI pipeline**

```
- powershell: |
    az pipelines variable-group variable update --group-id $(variableGroupId) --name $(variableName) --value $(variableValue)
  displayName: 'Store the variable in a group variable'
  env: 
    AZURE_DEVOPS_EXT_PAT: $(personalAccessToken)
```

Then all that's necessary, is to link the variable group to the release pipeline, and the variable will be seeded to that pipeline.