# How to consume variables from CI pipeline into CD pipeline directly

Tags: azure-devops, continuous-integration, azure-pipelines, continuous-deployment

How can I consume variables set in CI pipeline directly in CD pipeline?

Example:
If there are multiply variables declared in one group. How to access particular variable in CI/CD pipeline?

[image]

Also how to use variable groups for multiple keyvault's?

Thank you

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get the variable value in TFS/AzureDevOps from Build to Release Pipeline?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52568195/how-to-get-the-variable-value-in-tfs-azuredevops-from-build-to-release-pipeline)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setting up global variables

YAML

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/library/variable-groups?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml

CLASSIC

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/library/variable-groups?view=azure-devops&tabs=classic

Using Variables

YAML

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml%2Cbatch

CLASSIC

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=classic%2Cbatch

Examples:

```
Batch script: %VARIABLE_NAME%
PowerShell script: $env:VARIABLE_NAME
Bash script: $VARIABLE_NAME
```

Key Vault

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/library/variable-groups?view=azure-devops&tabs=classic#link-secrets-from-an-azure-key-vault

Answer (score 0):

Based on [Richard's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56428577/1198379) answer, I managed to set the value of a variable in a variable group to a variable coming from a CI pipeline, and then to read that variable in a CD pipeline.

For that, it is necessary:

- To have previously created the variable group, and the variable (its name identified by `$(variableName)`. Let's assume its value would be stored in `$(variableValue)`).
- To find the variable group ID (stored in `$(variableGroupId)`), which can be done by navigating on Azure DevOps to that variable group. The group ID will then be in the URL.
- A Personal Access Token (PAT) with Read & Write access to group variables (called `$(personalAccessToken)` )

**CI pipeline**

```
- powershell: |
    az pipelines variable-group variable update --group-id $(variableGroupId) --name $(variableName) --value $(variableValue)
  displayName: 'Store the variable in a group variable'
  env: 
    AZURE_DEVOPS_EXT_PAT: $(personalAccessToken)
```

Then all that's necessary, is to declare the variable group in the CD pipeline. If this variable group is called `MyVariableGroup`, it can be done in the following way:

**CD pipeline**

```
variables:
- group: MyVariableGroup
```

The variable that was previously set in the CI pipeline, will then be available in the CD pipeline.