# Azure Pipeline: Passing a variable from build to release pipeline

Tags: azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline, azure-pipelines-release-task

I'm building a docker image and use the `BuildNumber` as the image tag.
Later, on my release pipeline, I want to get this value and use it in `azure cli` task.
I know about `Build.TriggeredBy.BuildNumber` variable but the release might be triggered manually and I want it to use the buildNumber from the build task.
I thought about writing the value to a file and pack it into an artifact, but I can't see how to use it in the release pipeline.

Comment: Here is an extension - You save data into the artefact and release pipeline can extract it - https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=nkdagility.variablehydration

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A release pipeline must be associated to an artifacts from a build pipeline. You can directly use the buildNumber of the build with $(Build.BuildNumber) in your release pipeline.

Please refer to the [release variables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/release/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=batch). No matter your release pipeline is auto-triggered or manually triggered. It can always get the build number from the attached artifacts.

You can also define a variable group in the Library section and linked the group to your build and release pipeline, which allow build and release pipeline access to the same  variable. make sure allow access to all pipeline is enabled. You can use the predefined variables as shown in below pic. 
[image]. 
And link the variable group in your pipeline

[image]
For more information about variable group. Please refer to Microsoft [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/library/variable-groups?view=azure-devops&tabs=classic)

If above are not what you are looking for. These two tasks (Variable Save Task, Variable Load Task) may be helpful. Check this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52568195/how-to-get-the-variable-value-in-tfs-azuredevops-from-build-to-release-pipeline) for details.

Comment: I tried to use variable groups I assumed they would somehow be set and linked to the build/artefact but ended up not setting anything at all. It's a shame Release functionality in DevOps is so limited?? I ended up just setting my build name (artefact) to a more meaningful name that was good enough for me. +1