# How to access pipeline variable in AzureDevops during build process

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

How do I access, pipeline variables during the build process. see below. 
[image: Pipeline Variable]

This is what my simple test task looks like:

```
 steps:
      - bash: echo "Hello World!!! - $(Build.SourceBranch) and DeployType is $(TeamsChannel)"
        displayName: "Started building for $(Build.SourceBranch)"
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use this syntax `$(VariableName)` so in your case `$(TeamsChannel)`.

You are mixing a bit tersm here. You can have few places where you can define variable:

- pipeline variables tab
- variable groups
- yaml

Here you have all three cases:

```
variables:
- group: PROD
- name: my-bare-variable
  value: 'value of my-bare-variable'

steps:
- script: echo $(isProd) # variable defined in pipeline variables
- script: echo $(my-bare-variable) # variable defined in YAML
- script: echo $(name) # name is variable defined in PROD group
- task: Bash@3
  inputs:
    targetType: 'inline'
    script: 'env | sort'
```

Comment: it's saying command not found, if I add it in one of build task. So, like "variable groups" does it have to be referenced in variable section? if so, then how?

Answer (score 0):

**Update:**

After go through your screenshot, this should be a release pipeline. (Classic UI). But what you are using for test seems to be a yaml pipeline. It's not able to access release variable from a yaml pipeline directly. You should be able to use the variable in tasks of that release pipeline.

Also take a look at this similar question. [How to get the variable value in TFS/AzureDevOps from Build to Release Pipeline?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52568195/how-to-get-the-variable-value-in-tfs-azuredevops-from-build-to-release-pipeline)

---

If you are not familiar with variables in Azure DevOps. Suggest you first go through our official doc-- [Define variables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml%2Cbatch) It describe how to define/set variable,  the difference of system variable, system variable, environment, variable scope, secret variable.

Besides, you could also take a look at this blog-- [How to pass variables in Azure Pipelines YAML tasks](https://medium.com/microsoftazure/how-to-pass-variables-in-azure-pipelines-yaml-tasks-5c81c5d31763) which include three part:

- Passing variables between tasks in the same job
- Passing variables between jobs
- Passing variables between stages

Comment: sorry was my typo. I fixed it now in my original question. nonetheless it still says can't find the value.

Comment: @change198 After go through your screenshot, this should be a release pipeline. (Classic UI). But what you are using for test seems to be a yaml pipeline. It's not able to access release variable from a yaml pipeline directly. You should be able to use the variable in tasks of release.

Comment: thanks @Patrick, this is what I wanted to know. So, in short this is available in release task but not in build .

Comment: @change198 Yes. You could also take a look at this similar question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52568195/how-to-get-the-variable-value-in-tfs-azuredevops-from-build-to-release-pipeline Also update original reply.