# How do I access a custom variable from an azure build pipeline in an azure release pipeline?

Tags: variables, build, azure-devops, release

I added the custom variable like this:

```
  - task: Bash@3
    displayName: 'naming the artifact'
    inputs:
      targetType: 'inline'
      script: |
        an=FE_SNAPSHOT.zip
        echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=artifactName;]$an"
```

Now I am inside the deploy pipeline and would like to access the variable `artifactName` in a deploy bash script.

The variable is not listed in the "Initialize Job" step.

**UPDATE 1:**
The deployment pipeline has a trigger to the build pipeline and the build pipeline is linked as an artifact (in the artifacts section). Maybe this is another problem...

**SOLUTION:**
The linked ticket contains a part of my solution. The **BUILD PIPELINE** creates a simple file containing the value/variable I want to store:

```
  - task: Bash@3
    displayName: 'naming the artifact'
    inputs:
      targetType: 'inline'
      script: echo "FE_SNAPSHOT.zip" > $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/artifactName.value
```

The **DEPLOYMENT PIPELINE** reads the file and sets the variable:

```
  - task: Bash@3
    displayName: 'naming the artifact'
    inputs:
      targetType: 'inline'
      script: |
        an=`cat FE_CI_OS/drop/artifactName.value`
        echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=artifactName;]${an}"
```

Then it can be used in a next task as `$(artifactName)`.

Comment: Also maybe this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52568195/how-to-get-the-variable-value-in-tfs-azuredevops-from-build-to-release-pipeline

Answer (score 0):

Scope of this variable is a pipeline. And since this variable is set dynamically it it not listed in Initialize Job. It should be avaibale in your next task. Can you add right after this task

```yaml
- script: echo $(artifactName)
```

You should get your value displayed.

Comment: "Your build pipeline references an undefined variable named ‘artifactName’."

Comment: Just another hint: "right after this task" would be in the build pipeline. I need the variable in the linked deployment pipeline! Maybe a misunderstanding!?

Comment: So you want to set variable in build pipeline and reuse it in release pipeline right? Do you use mult-stage Yaml pipeline, or classic Release pipelines?