# how Access Variable in Azure script btw Powershell in Dev Ops Pipeline

Tags: azure-devops

In my yaml file I defined some variables which should contain the value of the month `($MinorVersion)` or year `($MajorVersion)`, by setting the value to `'$(Month)'` and/or `'$(Year:yy)'`. When I print them in the task script or task powershell it only displays `'$(Month)'` and/or `'$(Year:yy)'` . The expected output of the variable `$(MajorVersion)` is of course the current month and year `09` and `20`.

Can someone tell me how I can access the variable `$MinorVersion` in the task script / powershell to get the actual value of it? That's the files content:

```
trigger:
- master

pool:
  vmImage: 'windows-latest'

#import variable group resize-group, local variables are name/value pairs
variables:
- group: resize-group
- name: buildConfiguration
  value: 'Release'
- name: appxPackageDir
  value: '$(build.artifactStagingDirectory)\AppxPackages\\'
- name: MajorVersion
  value: '$(Year:yy)'
- name: MinorVersion
  value: '$(Month)'
- name: PatchVersion
  value: 45
- name: RevVersion
  value: '$(BuildID)'
- name: Packageappxmanifest
  value: Package.appxmanifest
- name: PackageVersion
  value: '$(MajorVersion).$(MinorVersion).$(PatchVersion).$(RevVersion)'


name: $(BuildDefinitionName)_$(MajorVersion).$(MinorVersion).$(PatchVersion)$(RevVersion)

steps:
- checkout: self
  submodules: true


- script: | 
     echo %MinorVersion%
     echo %variables.MinorVersion%
     echo $($[variables.MinorVersion])
     echo ${{ variables.MinorVersion }} # outputs initialValue
     echo $(Month)
     echo $(MajorVersion)
     echo $(MinorVersion)
     echo $(RevVersion)
     echo $(PackageVersion)
     echo $(Year:yyyy).$(Month).$(DayOfMonth)$(Rev:.r)

- powershell: |
    Write-Host  $env:MinorVersion
    Write-Host  $env:variables.MinorVersion%
    Write-Host "$env:MY_MAPPED_PACKAGEVERSION"
    Write-Host "$env:MY_MAPPED_REVVERSION"
```

Output only displays the unevaluated content of the variables:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can someone tell me how I can access the variable $MinorVersion in the
> task script / powershell to get the actual value of it?

Az devops doesn't have such System variables or Predefined variables like `$(Year:yy)` and `$(Month)`. The available predefined variables are defined [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml), we can't expand `$(Year:yy)` and `$(Month)` cause they're not predefined. As for `value: '$(BuildID)'`, the correct format of `BuildID` is `$(Build.BuildID)` instead of `$(BuildID)`.

The `$(Date:yyyyMMdd) and $(Rev:.r)` are something that only valid for Build Number(`name` for yaml pipeline), [related document here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/run-number?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml). So normal variables can't expand the value of them, only the `name` element can recognize them. You should use:

`name: $(BuildDefinitionName)_$(Date:yyyyMMdd)$(Rev:.r)`

Instead of wrong format:

`name: $(BuildDefinitionName)_$(MajorVersion).$(MinorVersion).xxx`

[image]

**Workaround to get/define variables with value of Date time:**

Though the variables of Date time are not predefined, we can put one PowerShell step at the start of `steps` to define those variables manually. You can check [link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58757262/date-variable-in-tfs) and [link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44738944/vsotfs-get-current-date-time-as-variable) for more details.

So if you want to define data-related variables, you can check [set variables in scripts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml%2Cpowershell#set-variables-in-scripts):

```
- task: PowerShell@2
  inputs:
    targetType: 'inline'
    script: |
      $year=$(Get-Date -Format 'yyyy')
      Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=MajorVersion]$year"
      $month=$(Get-Date -Format 'MM')
      Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=MinorVersion]$month"
      $day=$(Get-Date -Format 'dd')
      Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=DayOfMonth]$day"


- powershell: |
    Write-Host  $(MajorVersion)
    Write-Host  $(MinorVersion)
    Write-Host  $(DayOfMonth)
```

Output of second PS task:

[image]