# How to insert a formatted date into the filename of an Azure DevOps "Classic" Release Pipeline?

Tags: azure, date, devops, release

Note:  this is for the Azure DevOps **Classic** UI, not YAML.  I'm creating an Azure Release Pipeline ... how do we add a formatted date to a filename?  At work, we are still using the Classic UI, and YAML is not a choice at this moment.

In an Archive task, I want to append a formatted date to the zip filename, so the output zip name might be `MyBackupFile_20211022_0805.zip`,  (MyBackupFile_yyyyMMdd_HHmmss).

On a separate project, in a **Build** Pipeline, in the "Variables" tab, I successfully created a variable assigning it a value of a formatted date, like this,   [image], but this does not work in a Release Pipeline.

I also tried adding a variable using Powershell like the answer found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44738944/vsotfs-get-current-date-time-as-variable), but it doesn't work.  **EDIT:**  After using the technique in the link, it now works ... I wonder if the problem was creating the variable in the "Variables" tab, then using that same variable in the powershell? Or maybe it was a typo?

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly sure what solved it but here's what I did.

1, I went back to the variables tab and removed the previously created variable called "backupDateTime" which was populated with a value of "none" (following some other example).  Anyway, i deleted that variable.

2, I went back into the inline powershell script and added this

```
$DateTime = (Get-Date).ToString("yyyyMMdd_HHmm")
Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=backupDateTime;]$DateTime"
```

3, lastly, in the filename where a date was needed, added `$(backupDateTime)`, and it worked as expected.

Not an original solution, but it's fixed.